An 80's movie, that was a sequel (it was number 2 in the series)
That speaks about a guitar player that supposedly died in a car accident in the 60's but he actually lived to the 80's (that's when then movie takes place). He (the protagonist guitar player) works in construction, and reforms the band in the 80's glam rock scene teaching them some old school guitar feel tricks. Anyone have any idea what's the name of the movie? I watched it on TV once but not to the end, so i'm dying to find out the name and now how it ends! 

Just to clarify, the setting of the movie is the 80s, but did the movie also come out in the 80s?

Seconding the query above. This sounds really familiar, since there was a recent documentary about a real-life case of this. I think it was on Frontline, not more than a few months back.

No time left to add to my comment above. This is what I was refering to: Sugarman.

Sounds like Eddie and the Cruisers II: Eddie Lives, (1989).  The first in the series ended with Eddie, who everyone thought was dead, watching a news story about his posthumously released album on a television in the window of an electronics store.  In the sequel, 

A Montreal construction worker joins a band and turns out to be Eddie
  Wilson, a long-lost rock star from 1960s New Jersey.


Spot on, was def Eddie 2.
